# buttons on navigation bar not loading

Tags: iphone, ios4, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

i want to add buttons on navigation bar but its not loading on bar.Please help.Following is my code.please tell me where i am going wrong.The view i am using is landscape

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 32.0);
    navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    navBar.items = self.navigationController.navigationBar.items;
    navBar.delegate = self;
    //[navBar release];
    navBar.tintColor =[UIColor blackColor]      

    UIBarButtonItem * rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Photo"       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(takePhoto)];

    UIBarButtonItem * backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera List" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;   
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

    //navBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem  = rightButton; 
//  navBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];

    [backButton release];
}
```

Comment: Why r u adding another navBar in Ur UINavigationController app. What error ur getting? u r missing ; after navBar.tintColor =[UIColor blackColor]? statmt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
(void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 32.0); 
    navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:rect]; 
    navBar.items =   self.navigationController.navigationBar.items; 
    navBar.delegate = self; 

    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [UINavigationItem alloc];
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
    [navigationItem release];

    UIBarButtonItem * rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Photo" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(takePhoto)];

    UIBarButtonItem * backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera List" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];

    [backButton release]; 
    [rightButton release];
}
```

Comment: One thing about [`navigationItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW5) is that you should only use it when you are in a navigation controller. Alter your `self.navigationItem` to `navigationItem` to get the correct results.