# can I add a UIBarButtonItem completely IB free?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I created a nav bar and a label programmatically in my view controller. Now I want to add a "done" button but cant seem to find a way without using IB....is there any way to do that?

Here is my view controller's viewDidLoad:

```
//Adding navBar programmatically 
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,52)];
navBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:navBar];

//Adding label to navBar programmatically 
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,2,width-20,14)];
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
label.text = @"TITLE";
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[navBar addSubview:label];

//Adding back button to navBar programmatically 
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Last part obviously doesnt work...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps you sould read this [post][1] :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464920/buttons-on-navigation-bar-not-loading

Comment: Perhaps you sould read this [post][1] :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464920/buttons-on-navigation-bar-not-loading

Comment: He is using uinavigationcontoller, which I am not. It's a different case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using a `UIToolBar` instead?

To add buttons to a `UINavigationBar`, you need to create a `UINavigationItem`. If you're using `UINavigationBar` as part of `UINavigationController` (as is the common case), this is done automatically, as a standalone view, you have to do this yourself.

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""] autorelease];
item.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];
[navBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item] animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Agree about the toolbar - so why does the UINavigationBar is there then? what for if we suppose to use it only with uinavcontroller which adds it automatically anyway...? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The navigationItem is only used when you push a viewcontroller in a navigationcontroller

in your case you need to use

-pushNavigationItem:animated:

on the UINavigationBar

Check the docs for more details:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html